# Using GMail API to append content to Body and Recipients upon send

Tags: email, gmail-api

I'm developing a service that automatically adds certain content to an email when the user clicks send. To do so, the user connects his/her GMail account to our platform. After this, the service uses user context and user settings to add certain information or recipients to the email upon send. I've been searching for an appropriate method to edit the recipients and email body upon send but haven't found it so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: WIth Gmail API, once mail is send is sent, you cant edit it. But in your application itself, you can include "delayed send" where email can be delayed, so that  it will be still in drafts. When email is in draft, you can edit the content and recipients. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/update

Comment: That sounds like a feasible solution, thanks! Would I then use the code from this site for delayed send, of would you recommend a different approach? (Site:https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/source/checkout)

Answer (score 0):

WIth Gmail API, once mail is send is sent, you cant edit it. But in your application itself, you can include "delayed send" where email can be delayed, so that it will be still in drafts. When email is in draft, you can edit the content and recipients. developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/

Comment: This could be a good solution, however I'm not yet clear on how delayed-send would have to be implemented. It would basically have to decide to add an email address in BCC based on the values in To and CC. The only resource I found is this: http://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/source/checkout and I am not sure if this is the right one.